# Topology of the algebra $\mathbb{C}\{A\}$ for a LCA group $A$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a complex associative Hausdorff topological algebra, and let $A\subset\mathcal{A}$ be a locally compact Abelian (LCA) subgroup (multiplicative). The linear span $\mathbb{C}\{A\}$ has an induced topology as a subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$.

On the other hand, let $\hat A$ be the Pontrjiagin dual, so that $\phi:A\mapsto\hat{\hat A}\subset C(\hat A)$ is an isomorphism of LCA groups, where $C(\hat A)$ is given the topology of compact convergence. Now $\mathbb{C}\{A\}$ can be given the compact convergence topology of the subalgebra $\mathbb{C}\{\phi(A)\}\subset C(\hat A)$.

**Question:** Are the two topologies of the algebra $\mathbb{C}\{A\}$ above equivalent? More generally, how unique is the topology of $\mathbb{C}\{A\}$ given the LCA group $A$?

I assume that elements of $A$ are linearly independent in $\mathcal{A}$.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "elements of $A$ are linearly independent in $\mathcal{A}$"? it sounds absurd.

Comment: What exactly does sound to you like absurd?

Comment: If you have a linear space $\mathcal{A}$ and a subset $Z$, to say that "element of $Z$ are linearly independent in $\mathcal{A}$ has some standard sense", namely there is no nontrivial linear combination between them. If $0\in Z$, or if $Z$ contains some vector $v$ as well as $2v$, this is not the case.

Comment: First of all, $A\subset\mathcal{A}$ is a subGROUP, so $0\in A$ is excluded. Of course, it may happen that $A$ is not a linearly independent set. That is exactly why I have written that sentence. So, again, what is abusrd here?

Comment: Ok, you might have confused an additive subgroup with a multiplicative subgroup. If that is the case, I can understand. I will amend the statement.

Comment: Yes you mean $A\subset\mathcal{A}^\times$ a multiplicative subgroup, I indeed understood an additive subgroup.

Comment: If it were an additive subgroup, the multiplicative structure of $\mathcal{A}$ would be irrelevant, and it would be hard to make sense of $\mathbb{C}\{A\}$ as a subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$. This should have stopped the reader already in the first paragraph. Anyway, I have amended the statement. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: when I read contradictory statements, I try to fix them. So I understood $\mathbf{C}\{\mathcal{A}\}$ to be the subalgebra generated by $A$ and I asked about the meaning of the last sentence. I apologize not to have guessed the right meaning. Now it sounds clear.